# How to have my .exe separated from the .dll?

Tags: c++, dll, g++, mingw

I am using MinGW's g++ to compile some .dlls and then using those .dlls in some other programs. I would like to separate the .exe from the .dlls by putting the .dlls in a sub-folder but I don't know how. I would prefer solutions that don't involve make/cmake.

If it helps find an ideal solution, here is an example of how I'm building the dll:

```
g++ example.cpp -I. -shared -o example.dll
```

(I've got a script that simplifies adding many more files and dependencies. I'm not typing this into the terminal every time, don't worry!)

Thank you for any help or advice you can give, I always appreciate it greatly!

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from using DLLs in a subfolders? What don't you know how to do exactly? Please be more specific.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well if I put the DLL in a subfolder the EXE can't find them and it fails immediately.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 In other words either start your exe with the subfolder as working directory or the subfolder must be in the PATH. But please do not just add it gllbally to the system path unless you uderstand all implications. Instead laucnh your exe via a batch file or so in which you first set the PATH then start the exe. Anyway: why go through the hassle if you can just have the dlls in the same direcory as the exe?

Comment: [dynamic library search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

Comment: @NocturnalTom that happens only if you static link to the DLLs. If you load them dynamically instead, you can specify the path at runtime once your app is running.

Comment: Thanks, you guys! I guess it's all a little more trouble than it's worth but at least I know how it's done now. Appreciate the help!